# Face selection by condition

Tags: selection-tools, select

I have several similar mesh elements that form a sphere, so I wonder how possible to select just the external (top) part of the elements (not bottom, not side faces) for all elements at once. Any Ideas.

One mesh element of Body:
[image]

the Sphere form by those elements:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

**If the mesh origin is sphere center.**

For a perfect sphere with its origin (0, 0, 0) in its geometric center then the coordinate of any point is in the same direction as the normal.

As an example consider the cube with solidify modifier applied, its original faces are the outer skin, the new the interior, one method to test would be via a [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) being positive.

```
>>> for p in C.object.data.polygons:
...     p.index, p.center.dot(p.normal) > 0
...     
(0, True)
(1, True)
(2, True)
(3, True)
(4, True)
(5, True)
(6, False)
(7, False)
(8, False)
(9, False)
(10, False)
(11, False)
```

Notice the original six faces are outer, the new faces produced by modifier (indices 6 to 11) are inner that have normals pointing towards the origin.

Or similarly, can look at the angle between vectors, here is a script to run in edit mode, selects all faces where the angle between the face center coordinate and the face normal is less than 80 degrees.  (Change to suit. Side faces that are tangential to the sphere surface will be 90 degrees to the coordinate)

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from math import radians

context = bpy.context

ob = context.edit_object
me = ob.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
for f in bm.faces:
    f.select_set(f.normal.angle(f.calc_center_median()) < radians(80))
    
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Comment: Hmm,  smart and clever, I have to test it, thak you

Answer (score 1):

If it's round enough, you could add a sphere like so:
[image]

Merge the meshes, then box select all around it.
[image]

Deselect the new mesh with Shift-L with your mouse over it.
[image]

Shift-H to isolate selected. Now you can face select everything:
[image]

Maybe note-worthy, I had some limited success with Select Similar -> Coplanar.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am trying to find a more universal way by utilizing a conditional selection.

Comment: best I can think of is selecting all normals facing away from origin/3d cursor, probably with python. edit: *roughly* away. since those are separate objects, select similar coplanar might work with individual origins.

Comment: Thank you for your advice I will think about

Answer (score 0):

I found the actual answer: Select Linked Flat Faces is basically select linked with limited angle.

[image]